# checking if argument passed equals a string in bash script

Tags: bash

Little explanation necessary: why the hell does this doesn't work?

```
#!/bin/bash

ker=$1
if [ "$ker" != "iso" ] || [ "$ker" != "om" ] || [ "$ker" != "constbeta" ] ; then
 printf " allowed kernels: iso, om, constbeta \n"
 exit
fi
wait
echo 'anisotropy kernel: ', "$ker"
```

I have also tried

```
#!/bin/bash

ker="$1"
if [ $ker != "iso" ] || [ $ker != "om" ] || [ $ker != "constbeta" ] ; then
 printf " allowed kernels: iso, om, constbeta \n"
 exit
fi
wait
echo 'anisotropy kernel: ', "$ker"
```

I call it like this: `$ ./script.sh iso`
and I've even tried like this (though I think this doesn't make sense with the 
scripts above): `$ ./script.sh "iso"`
I always get `allowed kernels: iso, om, constbeta`
Many thanks to those who can spot the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of the logical or `||`, you should use and `&&` otherwise the condition is always true thinking to the negation string can't be equals to the three value.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an irrational condition...

```
if [ "$ker" != "iso" ] || [ "$ker" != "om" ] || [ "$ker" != "constbeta" ] ; then
```

If `$ker` is "iso", then it is not "om" and the condition matches. If `$ker` is "om" then it is not "iso" and the condition matches. What you want is to OR a list of positive checks and have an "else" condition, rather than OR the negative checks.

```
if [ "$ker" = "iso" ] || [ "$ker" = "om" ] || [ "$ker" = "constbeta" ] ; then
    : do something useful
else
    : report error
fi
```

Or, since you're in bash, you could use a "simpler" condition:

```
if [[ "$ker" =~ ^(iso|om|constbeta)$ ]]; then
```

Though if you like you could use other constructs:

```
case "$ker" in
  iso|om|constbeta)
    : this catches our "good" values
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Error" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

This has the possible benefit of being POSIX compliant.

Comment: I get it. thank you both. ps: your second suggestion doesn't work, but I'll figure our

Comment: @andrea - Varsågod, that's what we're here for. :)  What does the second suggestion do instead of working? Do you get an error?

Comment: no, it works. it just doesn't work the way I thought (ie the opposite). I still need to learn bash formatting syntax, I just never have time for that. tak så mycket!